# Fittext giving me odd sized headings

Tags: jquery

I'm using Fittext to resize text on my webpage but I'm getting odd results when trying to select two different uses of the h1 selector one within a header tag and the other used within Flexslider.

On the page heading:

```
<header><h1>A Main Heading</h1></header>
```

Within the Flexslider set up:

```
<ul class="slides">
<li>
    <article class="slide">
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.#.co.uk"><img src="_/images/thumb.jpg" alt="#" /></a>
        </div>
        <header><h1>Flexislide Heading</h1></header>
        <div class="slide-content">
            <p> some text </p>
        </div>
        <footer class="entry-meta">
            <p> some meta text </p>
        </footer>
    </article>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The Fittext call up:

```
// Fit Text
$().ready(function() {
$("h1").fitText(0.9);
$("h2").fitText(1.2);
$("h3").fitText(1.2);
$(".slide header h1").fitText(2.2);
});
```

The words appear in different sizes depending on how many letters are in a the second h1, some are fit nicely others that are short words appear tiny?

I was wondering if there is a better way to call the second set of h1 headings or if it's something to do with them being used in Flexslider?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider that h2-5 might be better elements to use, as it appears you're using h1 in two very different cases.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I am using the h1 slide heading in html5 so I'm splitting up in to different sections then using h1 heading for section article headings. I suppose it doesn't matter if they are h2 headings? (sorry for the late reply)